# How to sort on the Value of an member of a List<> within a parent List<>

Tags: c#, list, sorting, generics

I have a List sort question.  I am using c# 3.0 and a generic List structure like this:

```
public class myObject
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public List<mySetting> setting { get; set; }
}

public class mySetting
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }  // sort on this!
}
```

with this structure, I am filling a List of myObject with a LINQ query.

```
List<myObject> lmo = new List<myObject>();
lmo.SomeFillOperation():
```

What I want to do now is sort the entire `List<myObject>` on the individual `<mySetting>[].Value` values.  EDIT: ( So this would be sorting on one keyed index of  , for example mySetting[3].Value). I realize I could possibly do it in my `SomeFillOperation()`, but I want to do it after the List is formed.

Is there a recommended or easy way to do this?  Is there a good example you have seen? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You have a List of <mySetting>.Value's.  Which one determines whether that myObject comes before or after another one?

Comment: Sorry, necessary question, thanks Tom :  This would be sorting on one keyed index within List<mySetting> for example mySetting[3]).

Answer (score 5):

Well, `List<T>` already has a [`Sort`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3da4abas.aspx) method if you want to sort it in place - or you could use LINQ's [`OrderBy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.orderby.aspx) method. `OrderBy` is slightly easier than `Sort`:

```
var sorted = lmo.OrderBy(x => x.Value);
```

but even `Sort` isn't too bad:

```
lmo.Sort((x, y) => x.Value.CompareTo(y.Value));
```

EDIT: Having read the comment to the question, I no longer understand the question! Leaving this answer here as a potentially useful placeholder while I have dinner...

Answer (score 1):

```
int MyObjectComparison(MyObject x, MyObject y)
{
     return x.setting[0].Value.CompareTo(y.setting[0].Value);
}

lmo.Sort(MyObjectComparison);
```

Of course, this assumes that you want to use the Value of the first element in setting (and that setting is guarunteed to have at least one element).  Solution with less assumption will be forthcoming when more info is given.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using 3.0, use LINQ:

```
var newList = lmo.OrderBy(i => i.Value);
```

and

```
var newList = lmo.OrderByDescending(i => i.Value);
```